# Word wrap Metadata Navigation

Tags: metadata, quick-launch

I am trying to configure the master page to enable word wrap for the Metadata Navigation pane as the text is too long for the default width and the user has to expand it manually.

This is the code I am trying to use.

```
<style type="text/css"> 
    .ms-quicklaunch-navmgr {
      Word-Wrap: normal;
    } 
</style>
```

Does it matter where in the master page I put this?

Comment: Where exactly do you find this class ? Are you working on SharePoint 2013 or 2010?

Answer (score 1):

Since you seem to override corev14.css style, then ideally if you place your css just above the OOB `CssRegistration` tags will be a good solution. Otherwise you may need to use `!important` hack to see the effect.

**1.** Above `SharePoint:CssRegistration` tags

```
<style type="text/css"> 
    .ms-quicklaunch-navmgr {
      Word-Wrap: normal;
    } 
</style>

<SharePoint:CssRegistration ID="CssRegistration" Name="Themable/corev14.css" runat="server" />
```

**2.** Below `SharePoint:CssRegistration` tags

```
<SharePoint:CssRegistration ID="CssRegistration" Name="Themable/corev14.css" runat="server" />

<style type="text/css"> 
    .ms-quicklaunch-navmgr {
      Word-Wrap: normal!important;
    } 
</style>
```